# Crystal Reports Optional parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to display data from column **"user_id"** which is a main column and column **"pocket"**. User can have **many** pockets. My input parameters are ***user_id** and **pocket_id**.

**User_id** is mandatory and if there is **no pocket_id** in input parameter report should display all **user_id** pockets. But if ther is particular **pocket_id** report should display user_id and pocket_id from input parameters.

And I should do it without hasValue parameters because its return error in my database. and if I use is null construction data isn't complete.

my current code is:

```
If isnull{?Pocket ID} then {PocketID}else {?Pocket ID}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like this

If isnull{?Pocket ID} 
then {PocketID}={PocketID}
else {PocketID} in {?Pocket ID}

Comment: Ok, I have done what you said but I got error that
else {PocketID} in {?Pocket ID} should conatain integers, problably because my poskedID is int.

Comment: If your database field is integer then your parameter shiuld also be integer